# PDF report with table of contents containing page number in BIRT

Tags: birt, knime

I need to create a TOC on a report that will be produced as PDF.
Unfortunately, the TOC mechanism in BIRT when exporting to PDF is to add a bookmark.
However, I need to place a report like

Section A........................1

Section B........................4

Section C........................10

on the first page of the report.

I can't find anything on the books regarding this topic. What is the mechanism to do this?
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with BIRT.
What you could try is to create a TOC as usual.
Once the PDF is created with BIRT, you can use iText to read this TOC programatically and create a visible representation for it.

Comment: thanks for your reply, basicly i create my table of content but now my only issue i didn't find a sloution how can  add the page number of each row["section"] i tried to concatenate it this +numberPage but it gives me -> SectionA.....1 SectionB....1 (i mean it gives number 1 and that's wrong) could help abou that

Comment: You can obtain the page numbers from the TOC using iText.

Comment: could you send me  documnent of itext im new in BIRT